# Erro em redirecionamento de página - PHP

Tags: php

Tenho um formulário que envia por email a mensagem. Acontece que o código que eu tenho aqui parece não estar funcionando a parte de redirecionamento para página de confirmação ou erro de envio:

```
<?php

// Destinatário:
$para = "email@email.com";
// Assunto:
$assunto = "ASSUNTO X";
// Data de Envio:
$data_envio = date("d/m/Y h:i:s");

// Dados do Formulário:
$email = $_POST["email"];
$mensagem = "MSG X";
$mensagem .= "Enviado em $data_envio.";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $para\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: $para\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";

$envio = mail($para, $assunto, $mensagem, $headers);

        if($envio) {
            header("location:respostaform_ok.html");
        }
        else {
            header("location:respostaform_erro.html");
        }       

?>
```

Consigo receber a mensagem por email, mas o usuário que manda a msg não consegue ver a página de confirmação.

Alguém poderia ajudar? Obrigada.

Comment: Não pode ter nenhum output antes da função header, então verifique que não tenha echo, var_dump ou print_r dentro da sua função mail. E dê um exit logo após o header.

Answer (score -2):

Tem com a url completa do seu site, em vez de utilizar:

```
header("location:respostaform_ok.html");
```

Utilize assim:

```
header("location:http://seu-site.com.br/respostaform_ok.html");
```